# WPF : TextBox binding not working after using DataTemplateSelector/ContentTemplateSelector

Tags: wpf, data-binding, textbox, datatemplateselector

I am doing a tree view UI. I used DataTemplateSelector to decide whether to display a series of textbox or combobox dynamically based on a collection of data argument.

Please note in my code. ArugumentDetailsCollection is an observable collection containing ArgumentDetails class. DefaultValue is a string property in ArgumentDetails class. Please note the property is not dependency property

The problem is that DefaultValue is not bind to TextBox. When the TextBox is displayed, it contains empty string.

Please note the Textbox is working well if data template selector is not used. 
Please can someone advice ? thank you

```
                    <ItemsControl x:Name="argumentTexts" ItemsSource="{Binding ArgumentDetailsCollection}">
                        <ItemsControl.Resources>
                            <DataTemplate x:Key="TextBoxDataTemplate">
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=DefaultValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                         VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                         Width="Auto" 
                                         Margin="5,0,0,0"
                                         Padding="0" 
                                         Style="{StaticResource GridEditStyle}"
                                         IsEnabled="True"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxDataTemplate">
                                <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                         VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                         Width="Auto" 
                                         Margin="5,0,0,0"
                                         Padding="0" 
                                         Style="{StaticResource GridEditStyle}"
                                         IsEnabled="True"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                            <columnConfiguratorControls:ArgumentTypeTemplateSelector x:Key="ArgTemplateSelector" ComboBoxDataTemplate="{StaticResource ComboBoxDataTemplate}" TextBoxDataTemplate="{StaticResource TextBoxDataTemplate}"/>
                        </ItemsControl.Resources>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                             <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type structures:ArgumentDetails}">
                                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding VisibleName}"
                                                  ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ArgTemplateSelector}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing **Content="{Binding VisibleName}"** in your ContentControl will make the datacontext of the selected DataTemplate the VisibleName property. That's why you cannot access the **DefaultValue** property, since it's member of ArgumentDetails.

Change the binding to :

```
Content="{Binding}"
```

You will also need to review your ContentTemplateSelector class